# My sound keeps repeating in Unity whenever I press the left mouse button instead of playing once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on an FPS game in Unity using C#. This code is supposed to play a sound once whenever you press the left mouse button, but whenever I press it the sound plays repeatedly with no break between the sounds. I did find a question very similar to this one but I couldn't implement the answer into my code, Link: https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-play-a-sound-with-c.206152/. Any help will be appreciated.

```
    using UnityEngine;

    public class GunFire : MonoBehaviour
    {
        void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
            {
                AudioSource sound = gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
                sound.Play();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you click the button you want the sound to play. Then the problem is that you are using `GetButton` which returns true every frame that button is pressed.
Try using `GetButtonDown` which will only return true the first frame the button is pressed regardless of whether or not you are holding it.
Links to the API's pages for those functions : [GetButton](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButton.html), [GetButtonDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButtonDown.html)

You may also need to check if you have looping on or off on the audio source.

Answer (score -1):

Check your AudioSource for loop checkmark, it must be false
If you need loop true on this AudioSource, you can use [PlayOneShoot()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html) instead of Play().

p.s. Execute GetComponent() every time you need play the sound is a bad practice. It will be better to cashe it once.

Comment: PlayOneShot() does not work like that. Here is from the Unity Documentation: "AudioSource.PlayOneShot does not cancel clips that are already being played by AudioSource.PlayOneShot and AudioSource.Play."